# Realm: Filter with IN Operator

Tags: swift, realm

I have an array of Integers:

```
▿ 2 elements
  - [0] : 123459
  - [1] : 1031020
```

And would like to filter my objects based on the array.

```
.filter("code IN \(myCodeArray)")
```

But this results in a crash. How do I use the IN operator correctly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using Swift's string interpolation, you should use `NSPredicate`'s argument substitution support via `%@`:

```
.filter("code IN %@", myCodeArray)
```

Swift's string interpolation syntax (`"\(someVariable)"`) inserts a string representation of the variable into the string. The string representation of your array of integers is `[123459, 1031020]`, which is [not valid in an `NSPredicate` format string](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html). Using `%@` substitutes the object into the predicate without needing to worry about whether the Swift string representation of the object matches what `NSPredicate` expects.